# Cannot delete routing table in AWS using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x

In AWS, I have a VPC and a routing table. I created smallest playbook to delete it, and it looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Delete routing table
    ec2_vpc_route_table:
      vpc_id: "vpc-db5a65bf"
      route_table_id: "rtb-bb61b7dc"
      region: "eu-west-1"
      state: absent
```

All the IDs are ok. This is the result of running the playbook:

```
15:21 $ ansible-playbook shutdown_rt.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Delete routing table] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So it looks like the routing table is not there (`changed=0`), and it's not deleted. It still exists, as checked in AWS console.

Am I missing some module argument? Is it some bug? Is there some workaround?

Comment: Thanks, I will try with tags, but the documentation says "Tags are used to uniquely identify route tables within a VPC when the route_table_id is not supplied." It also makes more sense to identify route table by ID when available, doesn't it? Nevertheless, I'll try with tags.

Comment: `lookup: id` helped. Make it an answer so I can upvote it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on the documentation of the module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_route_table_module.html) it will by default do a lookup by tag and not by id. Since you haven't added any tags it simply refused to do anything.

Add the `lookup: id` parameter to make sure the module does a search by id instead of tags.